# Нет перевода в "Сортировка"

Tags: дефект, локализация, сортировка-ответов

Есть сортировка ответов. Но на английском.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: На Mете тоже нету перевода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и там еще есть непереведенная ссылка-кнопка "Reset to default"

Comment: Похоже, можно ставить метку "статус-завершено" https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDz7d.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил переводы:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17714
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17650
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17646
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17696
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17649
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17647

Будет в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2022.4.5.41860